# factors responsible for the number of touch in multi touch software/hardware concurrently

Tags: javascript, operating-system, screen, multi-touch, led

What factors affects the number of touch in a multi touch software/hardware? Does the java script framework used in software play an important role or is it just the OS and hardware dependent? I have a software requirement for a whiteboard software, the led screen in which the software has to be deployed accepts up to 20 touch. I want to get an understanding on the factors affecting this feature. Node.js in html5/css/js is what I have in mind for cross platform desktop application.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the number of touch points on a device is OS and hardware dependant.

Comment: Even I had the same concept of multi-touch, however one of the software companies stated that it depends on the java script framework used. I had tested used sketch.js in the 20 touch screen, although it registered all the points, it had minor issues with in annotating

Comment: A JavaScript framework might limit the number of touch points, but it certainly can't add more.

Comment: Can u please elaborate on that? Limit up to what number. Do you know any js framework that supports 'n' number of touches or maybe more than 30?

Comment: More than 30? What device supports more than 10?

Comment: Our led screens supports up to 20. In future we are planing to increase that.